# c++/win32 - LB_GETTEXT only returns one character

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

```
HWND listBox = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_SCORES_LIST);
LRESULT r = SendMessage (listBox , LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
LRESULT l = SendMessage (listBox , LB_GETTEXTLEN, (WPARAM)r, 0);
char* text = new char [l +1];
SendMessage (listBox, LB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)r, (LPARAM)text);
```

The result of this code should be that something like "Level 2" is stored in "text".  However for some reason at the end of this, only "L" is stored in "text".  I'm racking my brains for what could be causing this, but I can't think of anything.

Comment: Have you tried "wchar_t *text = new wchar_t[l + 1]"? Or change you project from Unicode to ANSI?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably compiling in UNICODE, so the functions you are calling operate with UTF-16 text. You should use `wchar_t` instead of `char`, or even better, the `TCHAR` macro (which maps to either `wchar_t` of `char` depending on whether you compile in UNICODE or ANSI).

Comment: `CHAR` always maps to `char`. You are thinking of `TCHAR` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Yup. Sorry; fast typing on the iPad always gets the best of me. Thanks.